How to design a battery charging circuit for solar panels and USB
I'm working on a low-power project using an esp32 and an e-paper display which will be used indoors. It uses a lithium ion battery. I want to harness solar power so the battery has be manually charged less often, or not at all. I thought of using this Great Scott design: https://oshwlab.com/GreatScott/SolarLiPoChargeProtectBoost
However, there's a problem. The solar cells I'm using have an open circuit voltage of 6V, but it drops dramatically under less optimal light conditions. Indoors, the open circuit voltage can be below 4V. So I thought I can simply use 2 cells in series and should get between 6 and 12 volts, but the  CN3791 which Scott uses will not charge if Vcc is below the set MPPT voltage (9V in my case). So indoors, it might just not charge at all.
The target power consumption of the device is 20mAh per day, if it can recharge 50%+ of that with solar indoors, it will be definitely worth it.
Why would anyone design a charging IC that doesn't charge below MPP voltage? I want to also be able to optionally charge with USB. A different charging IC (CN3170) from the same manufacturer shows how to connect two power supplies (solar and USB).
But the input is limited to 6V and it does not support MPPT.
Do I have to use a DC-DC converter to convert the voltages (solar or USB) to MPP voltage? Should I use a different IC for indoor applications and USB charging? Or should I even use 2 ICs, one for solar and one for USB?
Also, is it better to use the 2 cells in parallel or series? Maybe parallel with a 5V DC-DC converter is the best solution? If I would set the MPP voltage to 4.5V and charge with 5V USB, will the IC try to use as much current as possible to bring the voltage down, or will it stop at the maximum charge current setting?

I would forget about the mppt, it only adds 10-20% power best-case, in outdoor dynamic lighting, and actually consumes power to run the swithcing and computations, so in low-light where you need every mah, it's not worth it. Using 2 PVs in parallel to feed a 3170 is likely the best bet, or even an LDO regulator capped at 4.2v to trickle the batteries (use protected cells). That's not ideal for longevity, but is safe, simple, and low-drag. You might also consider nimh, which are trivial to trickle charge w/o any controllers.

@dandavis I decided on using a TP4056 because it has a low minimum voltage of 4V. However it wastes too much energy (not sure if it's the LED), so I also use an LDO with power good pin for the solar cells. It regulates to 4.3V, but if the voltage drops below 4V, which is always the case when charging, PG pin becomes active and will bypass both the LDO and the charger and connect the cells directly to the battery. Could that be a problem for trickle charge? The cells shouldn't provide more than a few mA indoors.
